# Does community domain name setup in Sandbox get rolled over to Production?

Tags: community

When you enable community, it asks to create a domain name.

In sandbox, while enabling community, I put my company name in domain and it was available. so I just created that.

Now, I just released that domain name is unique accross all Salesforce instances;

1. So would I be able to deploy it to Prod? or
2. Do I need to create a new one on Production- If I need to create new one then I will not be able to select my company name as I've selected it on sandbox already.

If 2nd point is true, then it is an issue; How to solve that without contacting Salesforce support?

However, if I create community domain name with "abc" directly in production and then refresh a sandbox then it does copy same in sandbox followed by sandbox pod no:

```
In prod:        https://abc.force.com/Customer
In sandbox:     https://devb-abc.cs60.force.com/Customer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sandbox, Production, and Developer Edition domain names will *never* conflict with each other; Sandboxes and Developer Edition orgs have additional text added to them (Sandboxes get the "sandbox name", while Developer Edition gets "-dev-ed"). You will need to create a new one in Production, but you can use the same name you used in your Sandbox. Once enabled, all future sandboxes will automatically also use that same name (with the Sandbox's name included in the domain). Finally, even if that were an issue, you could always just choose to delete the Sandbox, which would also free up the name, since it would no longer be in use.

Comment: Thanks Brian...wanted to confirm...so I would be good to create the same domain in production....is there any salesforce help article for that?

Comment: I was afraid of this is because of best answer selected by salesforce moderator for my domain stuff: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008qILIAY

Comment: @αΥβ As far as I can tell, it hasn't been an issue in years. However, you can "check availability" in production without committing, so why not just spend a minute in setup to confirm?

Comment: Yes..lemme do that.

Comment: @αΥβ Sure, always glad to help!